# User text disapear

Tags: html

I'm trying to put this 'TextField'-widgets in ibooks author and it works, but... if I advance to page 2 or 3 and then come back to the page where I created the 'TextField', all the user text has disappeared! How can I retain the text entered from the user in the TextField?

Thanx for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///System/Library/WidgetResources/AppleClasses/AppleAnimator.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///System/Library/WidgetResources/AppleClasses/AppleButton.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///System/Library/WidgetResources/AppleClasses/AppleInfoButton.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Parts/parts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="localizedStrings.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load();" apple-part="com.apple.Dashcode.part.StackLayout">
    <div id="front">
        <input id="textField" type="text" name="" value="" class="apple-textfield apple-no-children" apple-part="com.apple.Dashcode.part.textfield">
    </div>
    <div id="back">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this so I'll go over a few.

## Cookies

Given that you are already using JavaScript, we may as well continue using it. [This article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470821) has a very good explanation of how to use cookies in JavaScript, it also provides many examples. In case the link stagnates in the future, here is a relevant example from the page:

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
cookie_name = "dataCookie";
var YouEntered;

function putCookie() {

if(document.cookie != document.cookie) 
{index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);}
else 
{ index = -1;}

if (index == -1)
{
YouEntered=document.cf.cfd.value;
document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+YouEntered+"; expires=Monday, 04-Apr-2010 05:00:00 GMT";
}

}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="cf">

Enter A Word: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="cfd" size="20">
<INPUT TYPE="button" Value="Set to Cookie" 
onClick="putCookie()">

</FORM>
```

But, in my opinion, you may want to use PHP for using cookies as it is a server-side language meaning you won't have to rely on client-side interfaces which makes it more secure and provides a consistent result. There are plenty of resources out there for using cookies with PHP, so I would definitely recommend this over JavaScript.

In addition to this, cookies can take up lots of data and need to be cleared when no longer needed, so if you do decide to use PHP, use sessions instead (again there are hundreds of questions and articles related to PHP sessions).

## Webstorage

HTML 5 brought many wonders to us; and webstorage was one of them. This is just like cookies expect without all the crumbs: it's much much more simple. [W3School's page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is a nice overview of webstore, and something like [this website](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is a very in-depth tutorial and gives you a great idea of where to begin.

I haven't really looked at it much, and correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears to be less compatible with older browsers and it may not be that reliable/consistant. But that's the only downside I see.

## Requests

This is the one I least recommend, but it's still a valid option. To use POST, you need to use PHP or a server side programming language. You can pass parameters across pages without the user knowing: the only trouble is that you'll have to check for it and set it on every page from then. It does have the nice  You could derive the parameters from GET in JavaScript, but that just looks ugly for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep the user input in a variable in your main.js script and when you come back reload the elements using that as your value for your TextField.